# NSFoundationVersionNumber in iOS 11 - How to detect iOS version programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

In previous iOS versions I used `NSFoundationVersionNumber` to detect the iOS version:

```
#define IS_IOS10orHIGHER (floor(NSFoundationVersionNumber) > NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_9_x_Max)
#define IS_IOS9orHIGHER (floor(NSFoundationVersionNumber) > NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_8_3)
#define IS_IOS8orHIGHER (floor(NSFoundationVersionNumber) > NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_7_1)
#define IS_IOS7orHIGHER (floor(NSFoundationVersionNumber) > NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_6_1)
#define IS_IOS6orHIGHER (floor(NSFoundationVersionNumber) >= NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_6_0)
...
```

Now I would to do the same for iOS 11, but I was not able to find the correct `NSFoundationVersionNumber`. [The docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsfoundationversionnumber_ios_9_4) show `NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_9_x_Max` to be the latest.

**So, how is the correct `NSFoundationVersionNumber` to detect if iOS 11 is used?**

Answer (score 15, accepted):

One of the designated ways to get system version is with the systemVersion property of UIDevice.
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidevice/1620043-systemversion?language=objc

NSString *systemVersion = [[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion];

You can use it this way:

```
#define IS_IOS11orHIGHER ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 11.0)
```

Comment: Actually, there could be a glitch with this due to floating point arithmetic. `[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue]` is `11.1999998` on my system. The standard float rounding problem, so if I was looking for 11.2 this would fail.

Answer (score 84):

If you are using Xcode 9 or better, you can use the `@available` attribute:

```
if (@available(iOS 11.0, *)) {
    NSLog(@"newest");
} else {
    NSLog(@"not newest");
}
```

In Swift, it's the same, but spelled `#available` instead of `@available`.

The reason that this is a better way to do this than the other methods is because the compiler is aware of it, and will suppress availability warnings appropriately. So in the example above, you can use APIs that were introduced in iOS 11.0 within the `if` block without being warned about those APIs being unavailable to your project's deployment target.

Comment: I like this new approach :)

Comment: As per my comment above, the accepted answer can have a rounding error due to comparisons using floats - always a source of subtle errors. IMO this is the much better way.

Comment: To be clear, IMO this answer from @CharlesSrstka is correct and should be the accepted answer, not the one using a float comparison of the `systemVersion`, as that can cause subtle errors.

Comment: I get "@available does not guard availability here; use if (@available) instead"

Comment: @onmyway133 Is `@available` the only condition in your `if` statement, or do you combine it with something else via `&&` or `||`? The latter will get you that warning. Unfortunately the availability check has to be by itself.

Comment: @CharlesSrstka yeah I just noticed that, thanks for your answer

Comment: Does it check for iOS 11 and above or just iOS 11 ?

Comment: @KevinAmiranoff iOS 11 (or whichever version you check for) and above. If you need to specifically check for one particular OS version, you're probably better off using `NSProcessInfo`'s `operatingSystemVersion` property: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsprocessinfo/1410906-operatingsystemversion?language=objc

Answer (score 2):

[Apple NSProcessInfo](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/processinfo)

Apple now provides the NSOperatingSystemVersion struct in NSProcessInfo

You can use it with the isOperatingSystemAtLeastVersion:, or just check the 3 fields to exactly know which system version is running your app.

It is available in both obj c and swift